# How do i copy a checkbox value and keep the cell editable in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I've posted this question 2 days ago but with no answers. Here's a link to a copy of the file I'm working on:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TCQ0cWulb8Wm63Hs57ruwEXgpP1swKAi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110569351169109673921&rtpof=true&sd=true

Basically, what I've done is: the "effettivo" page is a copy of the "pianificazione" page, with all the cells in "effettivo" that copy its value from its relative. The trouble is: for the checkboxes on the right, the formula I've set (=pianificazione!G3, for example) copies the value but it renders the checkbox itself uneditable manually (= I can't click on the checkbox to change the value of that checkbox). I need to find a way to copy all those checkbox values from "pianificazione" to "effettivo" while mantaining the checkboxes themselves editable. Thanks again guys :)

Comment: The reason I didn't answer the question was that I don't know what you want and I'm not going to following the link to your spreadsheet to figure it out.  So I'd suggest you post everything in the question that's needed to explain it and also don't use any spanish word or sheet names because I don't know what they mean and often the names of the variable provide context to the explanation.

Comment: First your file is an XLSX file not a native Google spreadsheet.  Second I tried cut and paste and the checkboxs work in the copy so not sure what the problem is caused by.

Comment: Hi TheWiz! So, the document is an Excel sheet because the original is in my work drive, and I cant share a direct link, so I had to download the file and reupload it to my personal drive. Copying the checkbox values manually solves the problem, but I need it to be done automatically once the "pianificazione" file is wroten up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the document you provided is not Google sheet, but Excel sheets. To make checkboxes (or in my example whole data) two-ways editable from both sheets and show the same values in both sheets everytime. I suggest you save this document as Google sheet and use GAS onEdit() function. With this function you also able to mirror other changes in values, not only checkboxes. I built fast example based on your document [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDlBaWtC7Mwh-FEhiZM6Co0OTj3aH-62ACbyAXlTtnA/edit#gid=1833756091)

or you can just take over the function to your document

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var value = e.value;
    if (sheet.getName() == 'effettivo') {
        e.source.getSheetByName('pianificazione').getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(value);
    }
    if (sheet.getName() == 'pianificazione') {
        e.source.getSheetByName('effettivo').getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(value);
    }
}
```

**Important!** delete all formulas, that passes values between sheets, since that will be done by function, you don't need them anyway. Or just delete old 'effettivo' sheet and duplicate the 'pianificazione' and rename it to 'effettivo'. Also very important to authorize script first, best way to do it in Script editor trigger onEdit function manually and authorize it.

Comment: Hi Ricardas! Thanks for the answer :) so, the document is an Excel sheet because the original is in my work drive, and I cant share a direct link, so I had to download the file and reupload it to my personal drive. Then, I admit that i dont really know how to implement the formula you've given me... how do I open the script editor and implement the formula? Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: Did you try the functionality in demo sheet? You open script editor via "Extensions">"Apps Script" menu in toolbar. in Code.gs delete template function and paste my function, then run it once manually via "Run" button, authorize the script, close editor and prepare the sheet as I described. Or you just copy [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDlBaWtC7Mwh-FEhiZM6Co0OTj3aH-62ACbyAXlTtnA/edit#gid=1833756091) i created for you and use it...